# mod rewrite and htaccess with subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I had a site set up on one server, and it has subsequently been moved.
I had a subdomain that processed a link and forwarded it on. However, with the server move the files now sit in a different place!? Let me explain

### SERVER A

- `example.com` (run main site)
- `my.example.com`

I was able to create a subdomain and run files in it with no problem. The main domain and subdomain run like separate sites. My `.htaccess` file on that worked and had the following lines of code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ index.php?profileId=$1
```

### SERVER B

- `example.com` (run main site)
- `my.example.com` (the files now sit in a subfolder in the root of my main domain so `example.com/my.example.com`.)

This affects my `.htaccess` file now and although the subdomain is set up. When I run the page I get a "no input file specified error".

How do I resolve this? Its just a simple file to process but my issue is I have 10000 pre printed QR files that I am unable to change so need to resolve my issue.

Comment: Is this any cms, did you checked php ini for "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1"

Comment: What is the URL you are requesting? What does the subdomain have to do with this? (Why do you need a subdomain?) Presumably on **SERVER A**, both the main domain and subdomain point to the same place on the filesystem?

Comment: So we have a product that holds a unique id in a QR code.
my.domain.com/Bru7659 for example.
When scanned the user is sent to that page, it then uses the code to redict to a profile page on the site if there is data bound to the code or a page informing the user should there be no entry against the code.

The thing is that the product with the QR codes already exists (10 000) so I can not change that

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)$ index.php?profileId=$1
> ```

This should still work OK, assuming...

1. this `.htaccess` file is now in the document root of your subdomain (assumed to be `example.com/my.example.com`) and not the main domain's document root.
2. The `index.php` file (referenced in this directive) is located at `my.example.com/index.php` (not `example.com/index.php`).
3. Also, make sure that `MultiViews` is disabled. You might need to add the following to the top of your `.htaccess` file:

   ```
   Options -MultiViews
   ```

Comment: Thanks Mr White! It unfortunately doesnt work as the folder for the sub domain now resides in the root folder of the site

2.The index file referenced in indeed in the relevant sub domain folder but this is example.com/my.example.com/index.php

3. I will make the Multiviews edit on the file. thanks

Comment: Yes, but this should still be OK if the `.htaccess` file itself is also in the subdomain? If you are working entirely within the subdomain then the fact that the subdomain now points to a subdirectory off the main domain's document root is irrelevant.